# Avalonia Application Crashes on Keyboard Press in Linux Yocto

Tags: c#, linux, cross-platform, x11, avaloniaui

When using a Avalonia application in Linux Yocto, if you press any key on the keyboard at any moment when the window has focus,
the application will instantly crash and give a segmentation fault error.

The error occurs in the method Xutf8LookUpString from the /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 file.

This is only happening in Yocto Linux. The application works fine in Windows.

I was wondering if anyone experienced the same bug or has an idea on how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You may not have a keyboard attached.  Search following for keyboard : https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Turns out Avalonia is looking for `libx11-locale` when receiving keyboard events.

You can try adding the missing package to you app recipe.

```
 RDEPENDS_${PN} += "x11-locale"
```

You can also install `libxkbcommon`

This should fixed the segmentation fault.